# renamed page name in poweBI desktop doesn't refresh in poweBI service

Tags: powerbi

I renamed report page name to a new one in poweBI destop, and then I save and publish it.

Then I go to poweBI service side and observe that the page name is still shown as 'page1 of1 ' instead of the new name.

please refer to screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check you desktop app version, is it updated?

Earlier it was an issue in Power BI, later it corrected.

Comment: i updated it to latest version. now the version is 2.100.1401.0 64-bit(December 2021). but the issue still exits on powerBI service side.